# Sharepoint missing after upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012

Tags: sharepoint, upgrade

I recently upgraded from Team Foundation Server 2010 to Team Foundation Server 2012, after the database was restored and the Team Foundation Server 2012 was running on the new machine, i recognized that my new TFS 2012 is linking to my old TFS 2010 Sharepoint, so i installed the Extensions for Sharepoint on my new machine and Linked the TFS 2012 with the new Sharepoint.

To be sure that it doesnt link to my old machine, i shut it down. So my new Sharepoint is reachable on tfs:8080/tfs but I can't add a Team Project, and if I want to add a new collection, it adds it on tfs:8080/sites/DefaultCollection.

On adding a new Team Project to a upgraded Project, i get following Error Messages:
TF218017,TF250044

To upgrade I used http://blog.damianbrady.com.au/2012/06/03/upgrading-tfs2010-tfs2012-rc-done/

Does anyone know how I'm able to configure the Sharepoint site on tfs:8080/tfs?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Those specific errors occur when the user who is creating the TFS Team Project does not have the appropriate permissions on that SharePoint site collection to create sites. Add the user who is trying to create Team Projects as a Site Collection Administrator on the Site Collection you are using for TFS.

Comment: But i just can add 2 administrator for sharepoint, also, my site collections dont exist anymore, because they haven't been upgraded. How does it effect if i create the site collections?